# I need to know if the collection exists in Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have to check at what point in the login the user is in order to bring him to the right screen. To do this I need to know if the collection exists in the firebase db. How can I do?
I attach the main code that corresponds to the part where I have problems:

```
      home: utente == null
          ? const FirstPage()
          : utente!.providerData.length == 1
              ? utente!.emailVerified == false
                  ? VerificaEmailPage(email: utente?.email)

                  : // The condition must be entered here

                      ? const InserisciNumeroPage()
                      : const InserisciDatiPage()
              : const HomePage(),
```

[I attach photos of the Cloud Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/301nE.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "to know if the collection exists"? Which collection?

Comment: Each user who signs up has his own collection with his name, surname and other useful data inside. If this does not exist, I have to bring the user to the screen where it can be created.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot, to see it more clearly.

Comment: I did it. I apologize for my bad English and thank you.

Comment: As I see, your UID is the ID of the document, and not a collection, as you said before, right?

Comment: I'm so sorry for the confusion. I'm a beginner. I solved the problem using "FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection (" Users ") .doc (user! .Uid) .get () .toString (). IsEmpty".
Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work ;)